# my question is too broad

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[How does reddit's login validate credentials without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883737/how-does-reddits-login-work)

It's marked as "Too broad", but I don't understand why.

> There are either too many possible answers,

I hope not, it's a question about a really specific function of a particular site..

> or good answers would be too long for this format.

I'll take even an overview, like what methods/technologies are used, doesn't have to be a fully commented code. How do I edit it to make this clear?

> Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I'm really lost here, I can't narrow it down, if I could I wouldn't even be asking it in the first place...

Comment: You seem to be interested in a specific aspect of the UI. Try to clarify that even more. (My suspicion is, though, that the answer to your question is "Ajax.")

Comment: You are asking how authentication on a specific site works.  What do you expect?

Comment: @devnull I think the OP wants to know how the authentication is done without reloading the page.

Comment: @Pëkka Ah, ok!  I'd guess that submit triggers an AJAX call and if auth is not successful it displays the message instead of redirecting.

Comment: Many people just vote for the title, and never bothered with the content. So a super clear title is required. And a clear tile is more searchable for other future user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always make super clear what you are asking about, both in the question itself, and the title.

Choose a specific title. You'll agree "How does reddit's login work?" is much too broad.

An alternative suggestion might be

> How does reddit's login validate credentials without reloading the page?

And make it even clearer in the body what you are looking for.

(The technology you are likely looking for is called [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a convenient implementation. )